# Weird bug in sql script

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p.*, u.user_id, u.user_name, 
       COUNT(c.comment_id) AS count, 
       COUNT(v.vote_post_id) / 
         (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, v.vote_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) AS rate
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id)
LEFT JOIN post_votes AS v ON (p.post_id = v.vote_post_id)
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id) 
GROUP BY p.post_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(v.vote_post_id) / 
     (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, v.vote_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) DESC
```

This is the script I'm working on. I don't have my db filled up very well for testing, but the first two results gets double up with comments. Can you see any obvious mistakes here? I have another version of the script that works fine here:

```
SELECT p.*, u.user_id, u.user_name, 
       COUNT(c.comment_id) AS count
    FROM posts AS p 
    LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id) 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id) 
    GROUP BY p.post_id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(c.comment_post_id) / 
       (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, p.post_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) DESC
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Non ANSI SQL, like TIMESTAMPDIFF involved...)

Comment: what is exact output you want and what you getting specify that

Comment: It probably have something to do with that extra join in the first query

Comment: You have a one to many result in one of your joins.

Comment: I'm using a mysql db. My goal is to get the correct count of comments listed under the "AS count"

Comment: Your `post_votes` and your `comments` are getting multiplied by each other.  You can't just combine multiple one-to-many relations in a query without affecting the counts.  Since `post_votes` and `comments` aren't directly related to each other, they will cross-multiply when both are joined under `posts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple votes will cause your comments to duplicate.  You want to do a sub-select on the `post_votes` table to get the total votes per post as a single value if you `GROUP BY` the `vote_post_id`.

Since `COUNT` is a reserved word, I don't recommend using it as a column name in your result set.

If you're just getting the comment count and not the comments themselves, then you'll want that in a sub-select, too, or you'll be doubling up on posts.

```
SELECT p.*, u.user_id, u.user_name, c.comment_count, 
    v.vote_count AS total_votes, 
    v.vote_count / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, p.post_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) as votes_per_minute
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT comment_post_id, COUNT(comment_post_id) AS comment_count FROM comments GROUP BY comment_post_id) AS c ON (p.post_id = c.comment_post_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT vote_post_id, COUNT(vote_post_id) AS vote_count FROM post_votes GROUP BY vote_post_id) AS v ON (p.post_id = v.vote_post_id)
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (p.postedby_id = u.user_id) GROUP BY p.post_id 
ORDER BY v.vote_count / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, p.post_timestamp, SYSDATE()) + 1) DESC
```

Comment: When I try to run this query I get "#1054 - Unknown column 'v.vote_timestamp' in 'order clause' ". Can you help with that too?

Comment: Oh, right - you want to order by that timestamp, and I was not including that as part of the sub-select.  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with that calculation - is it votes per day?  If so, then that calculation will need to be part of the sub-select, and then you can return it in the outer `SELECT` and also order by it.

Comment: Its supposed to be a list of all the posts, ordered by whichever has the most votes per minute since it was created. But i need to get the count of all comments related to the post too for php purposes. I'm not really good at this stuff, and it's getting very complicated.

Comment: In your non-working version that I changed, the `ORDER BY` on the outer query didn't have access to that field.  If you just divide the total votes by the number of minutes since the post itself, I think you have your answer. I updated my answer to hopefully reflect this, although I don't have a way to run it.

Comment: Your last update did exactly what I needed, plus a little more. Didn't even think of mentioning I needed total_votes too! Perfect man, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. And just to make sure you know, your second, "working" version of the query will have the same problem with duplicating posts once it has multiple comments, in case you're using it anywhere else.  It will need the same sub-select treatment as the first one.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just copy the one you made me and change it. Like I said, this level of sql is currently out of my comfort zone. The one I posted that was working was something someone else from stackoverflow made. I'm sure I'll get it working though.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you are using MYSQL becasue it is the only database that allows this type of group by. It is a bad choice 100% of the time to use it however. You should group by all the fields in the select that are not part of the aggregate functions the way all other databases require. THis is how a group by needs to work.  This may clear your problem. It may not depending on the data. If you have multiple records in some of the joined tables and they happen to have differnt data in the some of the fields, you still may not get one record when you properly group. In that case, you need to write a derived table for the join or use an aggregate on the field that has more than one value to tell the database which value to use.

Comment: Yeah... I don't really know much about mysql and I'm in way over my head now. You're probably right, and I'll have to read more about joins and group by. Thanks for the help!